# Where does the C# specification clarify conversion of async lambda expressions to delegates?

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await

Microsoft's documentation states:

> Any lambda expression can be converted to a delegate type. The delegate type to which a lambda expression can be converted is defined by the types of its parameters and return value. If a lambda expression doesn't return a value, it can be converted to one of the `Action` delegate types; otherwise, it can be converted to one of the `Func` delegate types.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)

This documentation, though, does not explain the behavior of `async` lambda expressions, specifically ones lacking any `return` statement, being converted to delegate values.

If you are trying to convert to a `Func<Task>`, the conversion succeeds.

If you are trying to convert to an `Action`, the conversion succeeds and the anonymous method emitted for the lambda is `async void`.

If both `Action` and `Func<Task>` are options, then the compiler selects `Func<Task>`.

This all makes sense, but where is it *specified*? Per the above paragraph, it *shouldn't* work this way. The paragraph quoted above doesn't allow for async methods that don't return a value having a return type of `Task`. I've done some searching and haven't found anything covering this. It must be out there, though, right? :-)

Comment: You'd want to search the [Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction), not the Language reference, if you're after the dotted 'i's and crossed 't's.

Comment: Guess it's just the default design behavior. Using `async void` will make exceptions silent. Plus you can't await async void.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There isn't really a C# language specification anymore - all that's posted are various _draft_ specifications of old versions like C# 6 and C# 7. While newer features are documented (though often simply from their drafts or proposals - rarely anything marked "final") there still isn't a single coherent spec for C# 11. The ECMA spec repo is also kinda outdated: [the most recent spec version there is still C# 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/releases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That language reference isn't really the spec, although it's reasonably "spec-like".

The relevant section of the [draft C# 7 spec on the Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/readme) is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1071-general), based on the [ECMA standard GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard) repo with the section [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/conversions.md#10214-anonymous-function-conversions-and-method-group-conversions).

The relevant bullets in 10.7.1 for the conditions under which "an anonymous function `F` is compatible with a delegate type `D`" are:

> - If the body of `F` is an expression, and either `D` has a void return type or `F` is async and `D` has the return type `Task`, then when each parameter of `F` is given the type of the corresponding parameter in `D`, the body of `F` is a valid expression (w.r.t §11) that would be permitted as a *statement_expression* (§12.7).
> - If the body of `F` is a block, and either `D` has a void return type or F is async and `D` has the return type `Task`, then when each parameter of `F` is given the type of the corresponding parameter in `D`, the body of `F` is a valid block (w.r.t §12.3) in which no `return` statement specifies an expression.

Those are met for both `Action` and `Func<Task>` when considering an async lambda expression with no parameters and no return statements which specify expressions.

The fact that the conversion to `Func<Task>` is deemed better than the conversion to `Action` looks like it may be missing at the moment. I've raised [a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/issues/625) for this; it may be that there's something I've overlooked though (or that it wasn't specified in C# 7, and has been improved since then).